# Change URL hash while scrolling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen some jQuery plugins for this, but I was wondering if anybody did a service or a directive that does this. Google isn't helping.

Basically, what I'd like is for the URL to update every time I go over an element with (say, a directive and) an id so that if I go to another part of the application and click back I'm returned to the header that I was reading.

Comment: what will be the url when multiple elements are in view?

Answer (score 0):

## Use $anchorScroll and $location

These too services should give you the desired result.

The $location service allows you to change and get the # in the url

Where as the $anchorScroll lets you pin point places in the DOC.

[here](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) is a plunker demo

And here is the main controller

```
angular.module('anchorScrollExample', [])
.controller('ScrollController', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll',
  function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    $scope.gotoBottom = function() {
      // set the location.hash to the id of
      // the element you wish to scroll to.
      $location.hash('bottom');

      // call $anchorScroll()
      $anchorScroll();
    };
}]);
})(window.angular);
```

Best of luck

Comment: How does this update the url when user scrolls an element? When the element becomes visible on the viewport.

Comment: but the anchor on it and then update the url with location

Comment: This isn't at all what I asked. and your plunker is pretty much empty.